# Highcharts dynamically move dataLabel if it doesnt fit

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am trying to present the columns values at the top of each column so it is easier for the user to compare values.

I have got this working but when some columns are very close to each other some of the values aren't being dispalyed because I'm presuming highcharts works out that it wqouldnt fit unless it overlapped so it doesnt show the value.

Here is the code for my chart -

```
var chart_1_Options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container_chart_1',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            animation: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<p style="font-size: 8px;">' + this.y + '% </p>';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    }
};
```

Here is an image of what the chart looks like, I have circled areas where the value is missing

[image]

I just want the value to show even if it can't fit, I want it to place the value somewhere inside the column if it cant fit at the top.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try to find those labels and show them by doing something like code below:

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this;

    chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (p.dataLabel.translateY === -9999) {
          p.dataLabel.translate(p.dataLabel.alignAttr.x, p.dataLabel.alignAttr.y + 20)
          p.dataLabel.css({
            opacity: 1
          })
        }
      }, 50)
    })
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/unzgsmfr/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load